# why are /etc/rc.d/rcx.d files empty

Tags: scripting, terminal

As I was trying to find which services get started at each run level, I run `ls -l /etc/rc.d/rcx.d` and even manually browsed and open the files. But there seems to be nothing in there. Is this ordinary in Unix ?

Comment: It depends. What system/distribution are you using?

Comment: i am using CentOS 8

Comment: Centos 8 (and 7) uses [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), which does not make use of the legacy `/etc/rc.d/*` directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most mordern distributions use systemd init instead of legacy SYSV init.  /etc/rc.d/rc?.d were kept there for just compatibility.